# Stéphane Séjourné said that the Jewish state should not be accused of genocide. Is there any legal basis or support from politicians?

Tags: france, 2023-israel-hamas-war, gaza, genocide, south-africa

Last week, French politician Stéphane Séjourné responded to a question from Danièle Obono, a member of France's lower house of parliament, and replied that ["To accuse the Jewish state of genocide is to cross a moral threshold" and "the notion of genocide cannot be exploited for political ends."](https://www.nytimes.com/2024/01/17/world/middleeast/france-israel-genocide-gaza.html)

Is there any basis for his appeal to others to oppose South Africa's accusation based on this view? These bases may include legal grounds or positive statements by other political figures.

Comment: @Philipp the question is based on asking for motivation of a rather ambiguous statement. I made my best to clarify this in my (deleted) answer. I won't dispute the deletion, but I am surprised that you leave the question open.

Comment: @RogerV. I think my question is clear enough. I'm asking about the basis, not the motivation.

Comment: Genocide is exploited for political ends all the time, so that's nonsensical - accusations of genocide or of support for genocide fly around near constantly, and e.g. declarations on the Armenian genocide to attract Armenian voters are widespread, or accusing China of genocide as part of anti-Chinese policies, as are downplaying genocides for realpolitik (we need their oil, they can't possibly have done genocide). Questions about moral thresholds are nothing to do with politics and not susceptible to factual answers; that way to Philosophy SE.

Comment: This is a political argument, made in a political context, by a politician.  The answer seems, quite, trivially to be, no but is nevertheless on topic enough here. 
 Reopen.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The closure of the answer already tells us the answer.

Comment: closed, reopened, closed, reopened...  @ 2 full cycles, it's probably not a record, but...

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Haha, this is a collision of two ideas.

Comment: I voted to close because this is asking two questions, is there any legal basis for his view and does his view have any support.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica It looks like you just want to find an excuse to close the question, as the title says, my question only has one sentence, which seems like a double standard, but never mind, the question has been improved.

Comment: @yamakaze I might be missing something but how has the question been improved? Also I’m trying to remain as impartial as I can but this question was listed as needing review so I reviewed it according to the rules of this site. If the question was edited and/or split up into multiple I’d be more than happy to vote to re-open.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica My bad, I forgot to submit the edit.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica *closed, reopened, closed, reopened... @ 2 full cycles, it's probably not a record, but...* - there have been also answers deleted by Moderators, not  by voting.

Comment: @RogerV. Why can this question be closed for this reason? I would assume that most people would agree that what the French Foreign Minister is saying is completely wrong, so am I discrediting him by asking this?

Comment: I voted to reopen because although this could have been asked in bad faith, there is nothing in the question that indicates that this is the case, and it is best to assume good faith.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica it is not about bad faith or bias - the problem is that the Q invites speculations about the interpretation of an ambiguous statement by a dyslexic person.

Comment: @RogerV. The dyslexics will be delighted if you, as a proficient reader, could interpret the Foreign Minister's words for them.

Comment: @yamakaze I did, in my answer. I thought explaining was better than voting to close. But the moderators decided otherwise.

Comment: @RogerV. All I can say is that he did the right thing. Genocide is the most heinous crime and anyone who commits it or shields its perpetrators will not be tolerated. Can you tell me which moderator did this?

Comment: @yamakaze *All I can say is that he did the right thing.* - how can you be sure that it is the "right thing", if you didn't see the answer? But your comment does demonstrate the problem with accusing Israel in "genocide" - you want to put all the genocides on equal footing, e.g., suggesting that Holocaust and Naqba are in the same category.

Comment: @RogerV. Of course I saw it, and even though I was banned for a month, I still had access to the content. The reason why I was banned was because of my extreme words and deeds. Oops, at that time I was angered by that person's behavior of completely treating Palestinian lives as trivial, and I said some not-so-nice things in my anger. By the way, he likes to be an Israeli who likes to play Zelda.

Comment: @yamakaze so you know what the answer says: that Israel can be accused of genocide, just like any other state (as the SA is actually doing right now), but that this accusation is often misused for political reasons... which is callous towards the victims of real genocides. Seems like a trivial answer... which is again why the question should not be here.

Comment: @RogerV. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151358/discussion-between-yamakaze-and-roger-v).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is not clear what you mean by "legal basis". If you are asking whether he has a legal right to make these claims, then yes he does under France's free speech laws (even though these are [not applied uniformly](https://www.amnesty.org/en/latest/news/2020/11/france-is-not-the-free-speech-champion-it-says-it-is-2/)).

If you are asking whether his claims have any basis in reality, then clearly it does not. The ICJ has ruled that there is severe danger that Israel is engaging in genocide. From [Amnesty International](https://www.amnesty.org/en/latest/news/2024/01/israel-must-comply-with-key-icj-ruling-ordering-it-do-all-in-its-power-to-prevent-genocide-against-palestinians-in-gaza/):

> The stakes could not be higher – the ICJ’s provisional measures
> indicate that in the Court’s view the survival of Palestinians in Gaza
> is at risk

And:

> Amnesty International has warned of the risk of genocide in Gaza due
> to the shockingly high death toll among Palestinians, the widespread
> destruction caused by Israel’s relentless bombardment and the
> deliberate denial of humanitarian aid as part of the ongoing illegal
> blockade which are all inflicting horrifying levels of suffering on
> Gaza’s civilian population. Other warning signs include the increase
> in racist and dehumanizing rhetoric by some Israeli government
> officials, including Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu, and
> Israel’s history of oppressing and discriminating against Palestinians
> under its system of apartheid. In the face of a serious risk of
> genocide, all states are under an obligation under international law
> to act to prevent the commission of genocide.

So we have the ICJ and Amnesty International warning of genocide in Gaza. Clearly then, to accuse Israel of genocide is not to cross a "moral line" but to state facts as established by major international organisations.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, and is wrong to its core. Because the question is not if South Africa can substantiate its claim, but if there is legal basis to oppose South Africa's accusation - and there is.

Comment: ICJ took the case on, so yes, that would seem to support this claim.  *to state facts as established by major international organisations.* is putting it a bit strongly, the ICJ voiced its concern with regards to the possibility of genocide, it did not accept them as facts.

Comment: Amnesty has a [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Amnesty_International#Israel) of being accused of exaggerating Israel's culpability.  The statement quoted in this answer did not come from the court.  It is Amnesty's interpretation of the courts' decision.  There was no warning issued by ICJ of a genocide in Gaza, only an outline of a set of steps to be taken to avoid it.

Comment: "plausible" rather than "severe risk" is the word that the ICJ seems to have used https://www.npr.org/2024/01/26/1227078791/icj-israel-genocide-gaza-palestinians-south-africa

Comment: ^^ in re genocide. There was also something about a risk, but [it's](https://www.lawfaremedia.org/article/the-international-court-of-justice's-interim-measures-to-prevent-genocide-in-gaza) a little different than Amnesty paraphrased: "The catastrophic humanitarian situation in the Gaza Strip is at serious risk of deteriorating further".